# Bootstrap columns in triangle shape

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I could sound dumb asking this question,but please cooperate with me. I will try and explain it as cleanly as possible.

I have a Bootstrap row,which has two columns in it. Like so

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col firstCol"> Hello, </div>
        <div class="col secondCol"> World & </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to figure out is the firstCol & secondCol should be in right-angle triangle shaped like in the image.
[image]

I am aware that we can rotate the column but the content inside that column also gets rotated,but I am not looking for that. I am totally blank here,I am seeking help to start implementing this.

Comment: I think that this isn't possible, so I would like to see an answer to this question. You can rotate again the text inside the column using a new wrapper, but this will not result in the same text positioning of your example.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that and I have already mentioned that in my question. Anyway thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/) or [this](http://www.creativebloq.com/css3/how-create-pyramid-layout-css-31619524) might help you.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:relative;
}

html,body{
  min-height:100%;
}
  
.container{
  overflow:hidden;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
}
  
.shaped{
  height:100vh;
  width:40vw;
  float:right;
  background:black;
  -webkit-clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,30% 100%);
  -webkit-shape-margin:20px;
}

.content{
  padding:30px;
  color:black;
  font-size:15px;
  text-align:justify;
}

.content h1{
  font-size:90px;
  line-height:1;
  float:left;
  width:350px;
  height:100vh;
  margin-top:0;
  padding-top:20px;
  -webkit-shape-outside:polygon(0 0,100% 0,40% 100%,0 100%);
  shape-outside:polygon(0 0,100% 0,40% 100%,0 100%);
}

.content h1 span{
  font-size:.7em;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:-30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="shaped"></div>
<div class="content">
<h1><span>La</span> Tour <br/>Eiffel</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lobortis tempor rutrum. Sed eu odio rhoncus, molestie sapien eget, hendrerit elit. Aliquam at tellus a dui lacinia euismod a et dolor. Integer tempor leo ac quam sodales, sit amet sollicitudin risus facilisis. Donec sed purus non sapien consequat egestas. Curabitur laoreet aliquam leo, id vestibulum dui ornare sed. Nullam lectus felis, malesuada ac congue quis, suscipit vel ante. Mauris id tristique dui, quis malesuada enim. Curabitur neque quam, pellentesque ut libero sed, aliquam malesuada ligula. Donec accumsan augue nec dolor tincidunt, at sollicitudin dui scelerisque. Praesent quis dui quis lorem semper tempor eget porttitor leo.</p>
<p>Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam a dapibus mi, vel adipiscing lacus. Vivamus adipiscing urna eget ligula gravida, nec ultrices lorem tincidunt. Pellentesque arcu nulla, viverra ut dui et, fermentum gravida justo. Nullam eget ligula quis ligula convallis fringilla et vitae ligula. Sed ornare metus dictum, consectetur urna in, iaculis magna. Ut purus nibh, pretium id placerat sit amet, interdum ornare eros. Etiam ac viverra lectus, in gravida orci. Phasellus aliquam sapien vitae porttitor volutpat.</p>
<p>Nunc eu neque congue, aliquam nulla id, sagittis magna. Integer suscipit vulputate neque, placerat mattis ipsum congue at. Nam nec erat egestas, ullamcorper tellus id, fermentum diam. Nunc vestibulum massa eu metus hendrerit, quis consequat tellus tempus. Fusce mattis justo quis facilisis aliquet. Phasellus odio nibh, molestie eget leo a, pellentesque placerat lectus. Praesent est orci, dictum quis nibh a, vulputate vestibulum magna. Praesent cursus quam id dolor rutrum condimentum. Donec luctus lacus elit, at tincidunt massa ornare ac. Sed facilisis imperdiet nibh et adipiscing. Cras a tortor vitae sapien pellentesque iaculis in eu lorem. Integer fermentum eros libero, at dictum eros vestibulum non. Donec ac lectus urna. Praesent luctus purus sed ante vulputate convallis. Suspendisse tincidunt, purus in hendrerit ornare, felis risus mattis augue, non gravida turpis erat id ante.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am looking at it and will reply you after trying it out. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the help :)
Can you try and look into this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196210/shape-outside-property-not-working-at-all` issue.